# Best analytics/data visualization library for MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, analytics, data-visualization

In your opinion, what is the best library to crunch data AND build the web based reports in this context:

- Data: documents in MongoDB, less than 1M documents, time is a key dimension in the data
- Framework: Rails (but I'm opened to others)

There are tons of Javascript data visualization libraries, but ideally I'm looking for something that integrates "off-the-shelf" with MongoDB, and that uses modern technologies (HTML5) vs. old (Flash).

If I don't find anything MongoDB specific, I might go with either Google Chart or D3.js, which looks awesome but maybe too "young".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you already specified [D3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/), i heartily recommend [Cube](http://square.github.com/cube/) Time series visualization tool kit that built on

- Mongodb
- D3
- Node
- websocket

Its still in early development. But looks very promising. And one of the cool feature is it packed with websocket, this will be a interesting choice for real time data visualization for web. Have a look

Comment: Yes, I had already checked Cube. It looks extremely promising, but there are two showstoppers for me at this stage: 1/ no access control (charts are either internal, or totally public) 2/ charts are limited to simple lines (no pie, etc.). But the design of Cube is exactly the kind of library I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you use MoSQL,https://github.com/stripe/mosql, you can make your database a PostgresSQL instance and connect to Chartio.  Then you can use SQL to query your data.

You can see how MongoHQ is connecting their MongoDB data into Chartio here, http://chartio.com/blog/2014/02/mongodb-with-chartio

Answer (score 1):

To quickly provide a more current answer to a very old question:

[MongoDB Charts](https://www.mongodb.com/products/charts) is a first-party MongoDB tool designed to visualise data from your MongoDB collections. You can create charts with a drag and drop interface, arrange the charts onto your dashboards, and embed them into your own applications without code.

Charts is available as a part of MongoDB Atlas, or it can be installed as an on-prem server.

[image: MongoDB Charts screenshot]

Comment: Thanks @Tom - The embedded aspect is very cool.